# ARC two-way relationship

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa, automatic-ref-counting

So I want to have multiple nodes that are connected. Every node has outgoing and incoming connections. But the NSMutableArrays are creating leaks although i'm using ARC. How can i get the objects to be released properly? I'm already using an autoreleasepool.
[image: sketch]

The code so far is:

```
@interface TestObj()
@property(strong) NSMutableArray *incoming;
@property(strong) NSMutableArray *outgoing;
@end

@implementation TestObj
@synthesize incoming,outgoing;

- (id)init
{
    self = [super init];
    if (self) {
        incoming = [NSMutableArray array];
        outgoing = [NSMutableArray array];
    }
    return self;
}

-(void)addIncoming:(TestObj *)incomingN {
    if([incoming indexOfObject:incomingN] == NSNotFound) {
        [incoming addObject:incomingN];
        [incomingN addOutgoing:self];
    }
}

-(void)addOutgoing:(TestObj *)outgoingN {
    if([outgoing indexOfObject:outgoingN] == NSNotFound) {
        [outgoing addObject:outgoingN];
        [outgoingN addIncoming:self];
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With ARC, as with manual memory management on iOS, you need to avoid retain cycles. If you have one object that is retaining a second, and the second is retaining the first, those two will never be deallocated even if nothing else references them, so you have a memory leak.

You need to make it so that you aren't referencing them like this. `NSArray` and `NSMutableArray` keep strong references to other objects. You can do something like the following to create a weak reference that you can story in the array:

```
NSValue *val = [NSValue valueWithNonretainedObject:object];
```

If you store `val` in the array, it won't have a strong reference to the object, so it can be deallocated. However, you have to be careful that you aren't creating a situation where some of your objects have no strong references, or they will get deallocated before you want them to.

Comment: Great answer.  One addition: since you *know* about the retain cycle, you could alternatively solve the problem by removing the strong references later (for example, by removing the objects from the arrays).

Answer (score 0):

Well this may sound basic, but have tried setting them = to `nil`?